# Export to excel from javascript crashes chrome

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table with approx 40k rows. I am exporting this to an excel file using the following code. Although the code runs fine on firefox, it crashes on chrome.

function tabletoExcel(tableid, name) {

```
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/[…]/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
var base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))); };
var format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }); };
table = document.getElementById(tableid);
var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML};
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
```

}

Any suggestions........

Comment: Don't... do it that way? Seriously, though, you might be able to avoid it if you can figure out what's causing the crash. If it's the sheer size of the `data:` uri, then you're hosed, but if it's the `base64` or `format` functions, you ought to be able to operate on the string in chunks, rather than all in one go.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Chrome is only crashing when the table has ~ 30 K rows. It works fine till that limit. Can you elaborate on what you meant by operating in chunks. Cause the way i see it, i get to call the window.location.href only once to export the data

Comment: From the code above, you're doing three things, any of which might be at fault: 1) using a very big `data:` uri for the location, 2) doing a global search and replace on a very long string, and 3) doing base64 encoding (and subfunctions) on a very long string. If (1) is the problem, you need another approach. If (2) or (3) are the problems, they are susceptible to chunk processing.

Comment: Having this same issue though with far fewer rows. And it's working fine elsewhere on my site where more rows are being saved!